# GCC Version 10.1.0 failing on compilation of a BUILT IN function call in LFS "Illegal Instruction Internal Compiler Error"

Tags: gcc, linux-from-scratch, gcc10

My build is frozen this is figured out.
I'm using jhalfs to get started but the issue is most certainly gcc-10.1.0

I get the following error in the make log. The error outwardly says this a gcc thing... but.

```
`/sources/gcc-10.1.0/build/./gcc/xgcc -B/sources/gcc-10.1.0/build/./gcc/ -B/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/sys-include    -g -O2 -O2  -g -O2 -DIN_GCC    -W -Wall -Wno-narrowing -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wno-error=format-diag -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wno-error=format-diag -Wold-style-definition  -isystem ./include  -fpic -mlong-double-80 -DUSE_ELF_SYMVER  -g -DIN_LIBGCC2 -fbuilding-libgcc -fno-stack-protector  -fpic -mlong-double-80 -DUSE_ELF_SYMVER  -I. -I. -I../.././gcc -I../../../libgcc -I../../../libgcc/. -I../../../libgcc/../gcc -I../../../libgcc/../include -I../../../libgcc/config/libbid -DENABLE_DECIMAL_BID_FORMAT -DHAVE_CC_TLS  -DUSE_TLS -o _mulxc3.o -MT _mulxc3.o -MD -MP -MF _mulxc3.dep -DL_mulxc3 -c ../../../libgcc/libgcc2.c -fvisibility=hidden -DHIDE_EXPORTS
during RTL pass: expand
../../../libgcc/libgcc2.c: In function '__mulxc3':
../../../libgcc/libgcc2.c:1989:10: internal compiler error: Illegal instruction
 1989 |       if (isinf (a) || isinf (b))
      |          ^
libbacktrace could not find executable to open
Please submit a full bug report,
with preprocessed source if appropriate.
See <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugs/> for instructions.
make[3]: *** [Makefile:501: _mulxc3.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/sources/gcc-10.1.0/build/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/libgcc'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:13100: all-target-libgcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/sources/gcc-10.1.0/build'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:961: all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/sources/gcc-10.1.0/build'`
```

is there any workaround or solution or do I have to downgrade ?
What precisely happened that 10.1.0 was released buggy IF that is the case.

Some other similar but far from the same issues were solved by arch changes but i'm using the correct compiler and make system for my arch.

Comment: If this is a Linux From Scratch question, please include the book version and the chapter/section you're on, for starters.  If this is not a Linux From Scratch question, please remove the tag. In either case, GCC being 'released buggy' is much less likely than user error.

Comment: actually a version of for example llvm bombs gcc with a memory leak every time and freezes. one minor version release and it builds fine.

Comment: One minor version release of ...?